# http://localhost:4200 from windows is working with ng serve from WSL2, how come?

Tags: angular, windows, tomcat, wsl-2

When I run "ng serve" from WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04), I am able to access the angular application from Windows 10 Host by browsing to http://localhost:4200.

Can someone explain how this is possible?  I understand that WSL2 is working as a virtual machine with its own ip address.  How can Windows 10 host access the angular app on WSL2 using "http://localhost:4200" ?

On a different note, when I run tomcat from WSL2, I am NOT able to access the tomcat application from Windows using "http://localhost:8080".

Thanks in advance
Paul

Comment: I have similar observation also. With WSL1, the concept of `localhost` is the one main `localhost` of Windows. When I converted to WSL2, the WSL2 has it's own different `localhost` which is not the same `localhost` in the main Windows 10. But serving a listening port in WSL2 bash shell via `nc` is reachable from Windows IE explorer. But the opposite direction cannot make contact.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that `WSL2 is working as a virtual machine with its own ip address` depends on the Windows 10 version.

Also read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#accessing-linux-networking-apps-from-windows-localhost). It explains why and how.

#### Accessing Linux networking apps from Windows (localhost)

> If you are building a networking app (for example an app running on a
> NodeJS or SQL server) in your Linux distribution, you can access it
> from a Windows app (like your Edge or Chrome internet browser) using
> localhost (just like you normally would).
>
> However, if you are running an older version of Windows (Build 18945
> or less), you will need to get the IP address of the Linux host VM (or
> update to the latest Windows version).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: The default React server worked fine, but the Tomcat server wouldn't even if they were running on the same port. [Dudi Boy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64477209/1729441) suggests using a specific IP on older WSL versions, but that didn't help me much because I'm on a newer version. However, his link contained another useful piece of advice

> ## Connecting via remote IP addresses
>
> When using remote IP addresses to connect to your applications, they will be treated as connections from
> the Local Area Network (LAN). This means that you will need to make
> sure your application can accept LAN connections.
>
> For example, you may need to bind your application to `0.0.0.0`
> instead of `127.0.0.1`. In the example of a Python app using Flask,
> this can be done with the command: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`. Please
> keep security in mind when making these changes as this will allow
> connections from your LAN.

Sure enough, when I had my server run on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`, it worked!